# Relation between an equation and its interpretation as a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Say we had a function of the form $\sec^2(x) + p\tan(x) + q = 0$, if we solve it like a normal equation the solution would be $\tan(x) = \frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4(q+1)}}{2}$. But we could also interpret it as a differential equation $\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(x)) + p\tan(x) + q = 0$. Are both of this interpretations or their solutions related?

Could someone please explain this to me? I do have some experience with basic calculus but I have not studied differential equations yet. The question just came to me while solving a physics problem with such an equation.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you are confusing two different notions.

To solve an *equation* is to find the set of values for its variables which make the equation a true statement. Your first approach attempts that, fixing $x$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

To solve a *differential equation*, you need to find the set of *functions* which make the equation true. In your second case, I am not solving for a *function*. An example of a valid differential equation is $$y' + py + q = 0$$ where I would look for all possible functions $y = y(x)$ which make this equation true...

Comment: given that tan(x) is a solution to the differential equation y'+py+q = 0. Is it possible to relate tan(x) to the general solution and use that relation to solve for x on the first equation?

Comment: I've just realized that tan(x) is not necessarily a solution. It depends on the values  p and q. I guess it might be possible in some cases, but not in general